# How to compare two collections and archive documents which are not common

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have two collections for example CollectionA and CollectionB both have common filed which is hostname

Collection A :

```
    {

  "hostname": "vm01",
  "id": "1",
  "status": "online",

}
```

Collection B

```
{

  "hostname": "vm01",
  "id": "string",
  "installedversion": "string",

}

{

  "hostname": "vm02",
  "id": "string",
  "installedversion": "string",

}
```

what i want to achieve is when i receive a post message for collection B

- I want to check if the record exists in Collection B based on hostname and update all the values. if not insert the new record ( i have read it can be achieved by using upsert -- still looking how to make it work)

  - I want to check if the hostname is present in Collection A , if not move the record from collection B to another collection which is collection C ( as archive records).ie in the above hostname=vm02 record from collection B should be moved to collectionC

how can i achieve this using springboot mongodb anyhelp is appreciated.The code which i have to save the Collection B is as follows which i want to update to achieve the above desired result

```
public RscInstalltionStatusDTO save(RscInstalltionStatusDTO rscInstalltionStatusDTO) {
    log.debug("Request to save RscInstalltionStatus : {}", rscInstalltionStatusDTO);

    RscInstalltionStatus rscInstalltionStatus = rscInstalltionStatusMapper.toEntity(rscInstalltionStatusDTO);
    rscInstalltionStatus = rscInstalltionStatusRepository.save(rscInstalltionStatus);
    return rscInstalltionStatusMapper.toDto(rscInstalltionStatus);
}
```

**Update 1 :** The below works as i expected but I think there should be a better way to do this.

```
   public RscInstalltionStatusDTO save(RscInstalltionStatusDTO rscInstalltionStatusDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save RscInstalltionStatus : {}", rscInstalltionStatusDTO);


        RscInstalltionStatus rscInstalltionStatus = rscInstalltionStatusMapper.toEntity(rscInstalltionStatusDTO);
        System.out.print(rscInstalltionStatus.getHostname());
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("hostname").is(rscInstalltionStatus.getHostname()));
        Update update = new Update();
        update.set("configdownload",rscInstalltionStatus.getConfigdownload());
        update.set("rscpkgdownload",rscInstalltionStatus.getRscpkgdownload());
        update.set("configextraction",rscInstalltionStatus.getConfigextraction());
        update.set("rscpkgextraction",rscInstalltionStatus.getRscpkgextraction());
        update.set("rscstartup",rscInstalltionStatus.getRscstartup());
        update.set("installedversion",rscInstalltionStatus.getInstalledversion());
        mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update,RscInstalltionStatus.class);
        rscInstalltionStatus = rscInstalltionStatusRepository.findByHostname(rscInstalltionStatus.getHostname());
        return rscInstalltionStatusMapper.toDto(rscInstalltionStatus);
    }
```

Update2 : with the below code i am able to get move the records to another collection

```
String query = "{$lookup:{ from: \"vmdetails\",let: {rschostname: \"$hostname\"},pipeline:[{$match:{$expr:{$ne :[\"$hostname\",\"$$rschostname\"]}}}],as: \"rscInstall\"}},{$unwind:\"$rscInstall\"},{$project:{\"_id\":0,\"rscInstall\":0}}";
AggregationOperation rscInstalltionStatusTypedAggregation = new CustomProjectAggregationOperation(query);


LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().from("vmdetails").localField("hostname").foreignField("hostname").as("rscInstall");
UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("$rscInstall");

ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("_id","rscInstall").andExclude("_id","rscInstall");
OutOperation outOperation = Aggregation.out("RscInstallArchive");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(rscInstalltionStatusTypedAggregation,unwindOperation,projectionOperation,outOperation);
List<BasicDBObject> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,"rsc_installtion_status",BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults();
```

this issue which i have here is it returns multiple records

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @msparer pls see the update 1 section of what i have achieved so for .just trying to see how to move it to another collection ie archive records

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution , there may be other best solutions but for me this one worked

create a class customeAggregationGeneration (found in SO answers and extended to match my needs)

```
public class CustomProjectAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {

private String jsonOperation;

public CustomProjectAggregationOperation(String jsonOperation) {
    this.jsonOperation = jsonOperation;
}

@Override
public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
    return aggregationOperationContext.getMappedObject(Document.parse(jsonOperation));
}
}



  String lookupquery = "{$lookup :{from:\"vmdetails\",localField:\"hostname\",foreignField:\"hostname\"as:\"rscinstall\"}}";
        String matchquery = "{ $match: { \"rscinstall\": { $eq: [] } }}";
        String projectquery = "{$project:{\"rscinstall\":0}}";

        AggregationOperation lookupOpertaion = new CustomProjectAggregationOperation(lookupquery);
        AggregationOperation matchOperation = new CustomProjectAggregationOperation(matchquery);
        AggregationOperation projectOperation = new CustomProjectAggregationOperation(projectquery);

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOpertaion, matchOperation, projectOperation);
        ArrayList<Document> results1 = (ArrayList<Document>) mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "rsc_installtion_status", Document.class).getRawResults().get("result");

        // System.out.println(results1);

        for (Document doc : results1) {

         //   System.out.print(doc.get("_id").toString());
            mongoTemplate.insert(doc, "RscInstallArchive");
            delete(doc.get("_id").toString());
```